# Renting a WiFi hotspot in South Africa

Tags: cellphones, rental

I'll be visiting Johannesburg, South Africa in a few weeks. I want to rent a WiFi hotspot so that I can connect several devices to the Internet.  I've seen that Vodacom rents these, and they can be picked up at the airport.

I will only be using this in the vicinity of Johannesburg.  Is there a better choice than Vodacom?

Edited: changed Vodaphone to Vodacom.

Comment: BTW, there is no Vodafone (or Vodaphone) in South Africa. It is called "Vodacom".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Vodafone is a good option and other than that, you can opt for Tep wireless connection. It is handheld device that act like a WiFi-hotspot and provides wireless connection anywhere in South Africa.